# Logging VMStat data to file

Tags: linux, unix

I am trying to create some capacity planning reports and one of the requrements is to have info on Memory usage for a few Unix Servers.

Now my knowledge of Unix is very low. I usually just log on and run a few scripts.

But for this report I need to gather VMStat data and produce reports based on previous the previous weeks data broken down by hour which is an average of Vmstat data taken every 10 seconds.

So first question: is VMStat logging on by default and if so what location on the server is the data output to?

If not how can I set this up?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`vmstat` is a command that you run.

To generate one week of Virtual Memory stats spaced out at ten second intervals (less the last one) is 60,479 10 second intervals

So the command you want is:

```
nohup vmstat 10 604879 > myvmstatfile.dat &
```

**This will make a very big file myvmstatfile.dat**

EDIT: RobKielty (The `&` will put this job in the background, the `nohup` will prevent the task from hanging up when you logout of the command shell. If you ran this command it would be prudent to monitor the disk partition to which this file was being written to. Use `df -h /path/to/directory/where/outputfile/resides` to monitor the disk space usage.)

I have no idea what you need to do with the data, so I can't help you there.

Create a [crontab](/questions/tagged/crontab) entry (crontab -e) like this

```
0 0 * * 0  /path/to/my/vmstat_script.sh
```

The file `vmstat_script.sh` will contain the follow bash script commands.

```
#!/bin/bash
# vmstat_script.sh
vmstat 10 604879 > myvmstatfile.dat
mv myvmstatfile.dat myvmstatfile.dat.`date +%Y-%m-%d`
```

This will create one file per week with a name like `myvmstatfile.dat.2012-07-01`

Comment: @Rob Kielty - Why does this look to me that it will run for 70, instead of 7 days (604879×10÷60÷60÷24 = 70)? What am I missing?

Comment: @MuhamedHuseinbašić I would divide by 10 instead of multiplying by 10

Comment: @RobKielty - I still don't get it. This line: vmstat 10 604879 says to output one line every 10 seconds and to stop after 604879 lines. So if for 1 line we need 10 seconds, for 604879 lines we need 604879 times 10 seconds. That means the script will be running for 6048790 seconds, which is approx. equal to 70 days. What is my mistake here?

Comment: Ah I see your point now. When I edited this I left the vmstat command unchanged. So you are proposing that the second argument is divided by 10 to read say vmstat 10 60488 ?

Comment: @RobKielty - Exactly. :)

Comment: @RobKielty - :D - I cannot propose it since it is just one character edit. That's why I tagged you - I think you can edit it without approval since you edited it once already.

Comment: I'll take a look when I get a chance. I'll credit your effort on the edit.

Answer (score 1):

The command I use for monitoring the Linux vm metrics is below:
nohup vmstat 10 720| (while read; do echo "$(date +%d-%m-%Y" "%H:%M:%S) $REPLY"; done) >> nameofLogfile.log

Here nohup is used for running the process in background.
It will run for 2 hours with interval of 10 secs.
This is the best command for generating graphs and reports as timestamp will also be included in logs along with different metrics, so that we can filter the logs accordingly.